# How to get work data by recording ID using MusicBrainz Json API?

Tags: musicbrainz

Many tracks in my library have no language information. It appears that MusicBrainz does not provide language information for a recording, only for a work.

How can I get a work ID if I know recording ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link a `work` to a `recording` through a [performance](https://musicbrainz.org/relationships/recording-work#).

> Forward link phrase: {live} {medley:medley including a} {partial} {instrumental} {cover} recording of
>
> Reverse link phrase: {live} {medley:medleys including} {partial} {instrumental} {cover} recordings
>
> Long link phrase: is a {live} {medley:medley including a} {partial} {instrumental} {cover} recording of
>
> Description: This is used to link works to their recordings.
>
> entity0 cardinality: Few relationships (0)
>
> entity1 cardinality: Many relationships (1)
>
> UUID: a3005666-a872-32c3-ad06-98af558e99b0

Performances are explained in more detail in [the documentation](https://musicbrainz.org/relationship/a3005666-a872-32c3-ad06-98af558e99b0).

Here's an example of the relationship:

> A Day in the Life (original stereo studio mix) by The Beatles is a recording of A Day in the Life
>
> A Day in the Life by Affinity is a live instrumental cover recording of A Day in the Life

**edit:**

As you have commented, you need the relationship in the opposite direction, and this call does the trick:

```
http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/fcbcdc39-8851-4efc-a02a-ab0e13be224f?inc=‌​work-rels&fmt=json
```

Comment: @AndreiVolgin looks like it, see the bottom of [this page](https://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Development/JSON_Web_Service)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I actually need it in the opposite direction, but this call seems to do the trick: `http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/fcbcdc39-8851-4efc-a02a-ab0e13be224f?inc=work-rels&fmt=json`   Can you add it to your answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin sounds good, glad I could help! added the edit at the bottom

Comment: The response I'm getting from your url is: 
`"error": "‌​work-rels is not a valid inc parameter for the recording resource."`